# Как сделать если изображение меньше 700px то не ресайзим?

Tags: php

делаю функцию ресайза изображения для парсера из ютуба , оригинальные изображения слишком большие в maxresdefault но качественные .Как сделать если изображение меньше 700px то не ресайзим?
вот сама функция

```
   # Функция для загрузки и ресайза изображений
function youtube_thumb($thumb, $youtube_thumb, $preview_path, $original_path, $size )
{
    /*
     * $thumb - новое имя на изображение 
     * $youtube_thumb - ссылка на изображение 
     * $preview_path - папка, куда сохраняем превьюшки
     * $original_path - папка, куда сохраняем оригинал
     * $size - размер большей стороны (в пикселях)
    */

    # Получаем изображение. Если функция не отработала
    if( $image = file_get_contents( $youtube_thumb ) )
    {

        # Сохраняем изображение            
        file_put_contents( $thumb, $image );

        # Очищаем память
        unset( $image );

        # Если getimagesize вернула массив
        if( $info = getimagesize( $thumb ) )
        {
            # Вычисляем тип изображения
            $type = trim( strrchr( $info['mime'], '/' ), '/' );

            # Исходя из типа формируем названия функций
            $imagecreate = 'imagecreatefrom' . $type;
            $imagesave = 'image' . $type;
            $imagename = $thumb;

            # Получаем данные об изображении
            list( $width, $height ) = $info;

            # Создаём ресурс изображения
            $src_im = $imagecreate( $thumb );

            # Вычисляем ширину
            $new_width = $width > $height ? $size : ceil( ( $width * $size ) / $height );

            # Вычисляем высоту
            $new_height = $width < $height ? $size : ceil( ( $height * $size ) / $width );

            # Создаём новое изображение
            $dst_im = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

            # Ресайзим
            imagecopyresampled( $dst_im, $src_im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

            # Чистим память
            unset( $src_im );

            # Сохраняем оригинал
            if( !copy( $youtube_thumb, $original_path . $imagename ) ) $return = false;                

            # Сохраняем превьюшку
            if( !$imagesave( $dst_im, $preview_path . $imagename ) ) $return = false;

            # Очищаем память
            unset( $dst_im );
            unlink( $thumb );

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if($width<700){ # Ресайзим imagecopyresampled( $dst_im, $src_im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height ); }`???

Comment: так создает пустой черный рисунок

Answer (score 0):

Кажется вот так работает 
`

```
        #если изображение меньше $size то не ресайзим
        if($width <= $size) {$new_width = $width; $new_height = $height;}

        # Создаём новое изображение`
```